# How to sort by smaller Numbers to Larger Numbers in smart table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

The following is my code, When user clicks the **th** title **ID**
it will sort by ID number 
(1->2->3->-11->23)
but the result is (1->11->2->23->3)
I hope the result is sort by smaller Numbers to Larger Numbers or Larger Numbers to smaller Numbers.....I don't want to add zero in single number.....

```
<div class='container' ng-app='smarttabledemo' ng-controller='smarttabledemo'>
      <h3>Smart-Table</h3>
      <table st-table='data' class='table'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th st-sort='ID'>ID</th>
            <th st-sort='firstName'>First Name</th>
            <th st-sort='lastName'>Last Name</th>
            <th st-sort='phone'>Phone Number</th>
            <th st-sort='hometown'>Hometown</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr st-select-row='row' ng-repeat='row in data'>
          <td>{{row.ID}}</td>
            <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{row.hometown}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
```

my json file

```
  $scope.data = [
    { ID: '3',firstName: 'Sam', lastName: 'Evans', phone: 'Not Provide', hometown: 'Anytown, ST' },
    { ID: '23',firstName: 'Saul', lastName: 'Evans', phone: '555-555-1234', hometown: 'Anytown, ST' },
    { ID: '1',firstName: 'Charlie', lastName: 'Anders', phone: '555-555-9876', hometown: 'Springfield, ST' },
    { ID: '2',firstName: 'Jessica', lastName: 'Cortez', phone: 'Not Provide', hometown: 'Springfield, ST' },
    { ID: '11',firstName: 'Amy', lastName: 'Wood', phone: '555-555-1348', hometown: 'Metroville, ST' },
  ]
```

[image]

The following is my fiddle demo, Thanks
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwc5s6qt/4/)

Comment: Just change the data type of ID to numbers: https://jsfiddle.net/rpt21uLw/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `ID` is a string so it's sorting alpha and not numerically.

Change all the `ID` to a number, or if you don't want to do the work, insert this after you assign the array:

```
$scope.data.forEach(o=>o.ID=+o.ID)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qwc5s6qt/6/

Otherwise, update the data or your Angular getter for a custom sort function.

Answer (score -4):

**you can use**

```
$scope.data.sort((a, b) => a.ID - b.ID)
```

Comment: I just give you an example